# Caught a fatal signal: SIGBUS(7) on node 2/32

Tags: mpi, sigpipe, sigbus

I'm trying to run NAS-UPC benchmarks on a 32 node cluster.

It works fine in cases where the problem size is small . When I graduate to a bigger problem size (CLASS D), I get this error (for MG benchmark)

```
*** Caught a fatal signal: SIGBUS(7) on node 2/32
 p4_error: latest msg from perror: Bad file descriptor
*** Caught a signal: SIGPIPE(13) on node 0/32
    p4_error: latest msg from perror: Bad file descriptor
   p4_error: latest msg from perror: Bad file descriptor

*** FATAL ERROR: recursion failure in AMMPI_SPMDExit
*** Caught a signal: SIGPIPE(13) on node 27/32
*** Caught a signal: SIGPIPE(13) on node 20/32
*** Caught a signal: SIGPIPE(13) on node 21/32
    p4_error: latest msg from perror: Bad file descriptor
*** FATAL ERROR: recursion failure in AMMPI_SPMDExit
*** FATAL ERROR: recursion failure in AMMPI_SPMDExit
*** FATAL ERROR: recursion failure in AMMPI_SPMDExit
*** Caught a signal: SIGPIPE(13) on node 16/32
*** FATAL ERROR: recursion failure in AMMPI_SPMDExit
```

Can anybody explain why this is happening , And if anyone has seen this error before and fixed it ?

EDIT : Figured out it is a memory related problem . But I'm unable to allott right amount of memory for application at compile time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it is a problem with benchmark needing more memory than i had allotted it during compile time.

Comment: When you accept your own answers, they will not be moved to the top, and +2 reputation is not given.

Answer (score 2):

Check a `dmesg` output - it can be an out-of-memory issue. Or, again, it can be a some from `ulimit -a` hitted, e.g. a stacksize (default stack size is too small for some NAS tasks).

If you have a lines like  "Out of Memory: Killed process ###" in `dmesg` output on any of your machines - it means that your program required (and tried to use) a lot of memory, bigger than your OS can give to the application. There are several limits of memory:

1. `ulimit -v`  - user limit for virtual memory size. Check all `ulimit -a` limits also, but seems that your case is not this
2. You can use not more memory than you have total RAM and all swap sizes (check with `free` command). But if your application uses more memory than RAM size, and begin to do swapping - the performance will be bad (in most cases).
3. There are architectural limits of maximum memory, allowable to single process to have. For 32-bit nodes this limit can be from 1(very rare case) to 2, 3, 4 GB. Even if your 32-bit system have >4 GB of memory, e.g. with using of PAE - no single process can take > 4 Gb. A big part of 4Gb virtual space also taken by OS (from hundreds of MB up to GBs).

Comment: I set stack to unlimited, but the problem persists. 
(ulimit -s unlimited)..

IS there any way I could counter this out-of-memory problem?

Comment: @Sharat Chandra, did you checked a `dmesg` output after a failure to verify is it actually an OOM (out of memory) or anything another?

Comment: I did , but i do not know how to interpret the output. could you tell me what I should look for from that output ? you should kindly excuse my ignorance in this matter :(

Comment: Is there a line like "Out of Memory: Killed process ..." in dmesg or in system log (grep in `/var/log/*`)?